# Imagemagick stick images next to each other

Tags: image, imagemagick, png, imagick

How can I create an Image using Imagemagick in which I stick for example 6 images next to each other, thus the background shall be transparent(.png file).

It shall look something like this: ( The black rectangles shall represent images )

[image]

How do I achieve this ?

**Edit (Update)**

So far I have done this image:

[image]

using this command:

```
montage img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg img4.jpg img5.jpg img6.jpg -geometry +10+10 -resize 720x480 output.jpg
```

but I am not sure how to proceed further.

Comment: Image Magick has great pages on usage, in this case try 'montage' function and read tutorials on http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/

Comment: looks good thank you

Comment: @rostok I cannot seem to handle my problem do you mind having a look at it?

Comment: ok, my answer is below

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there! Take your `montage` command and output the resulting 3x2 montage to `stdout` as a `PNG` into a new `convert` which appends it below your `top.jpg` image:

```
montage im*jpg -geometry +10+10 png:- | convert -gravity north top.jpg png:- -append result.png
```

[image]

If you are on Windows, you probably need:

```
montage *.jpg ...
```

or you can type it out in full:

```
montage img1.jpg img2.jpg img3.jpg img4.jpg img5.jpg img6.jpg -geometry +10+10 png:- | convert -gravity north top.jpg png:- -append result.png
```

Comment: It means all files starting with `im` and ending in `jpg`. It's just shorter to type.

Comment: ah ok I see, what would it look like in the longer version?

Comment: if I run your code / command (short version) I get following message in my console convert.exe: improper image header `-' @ error/png.c/ReadPNGImage/3986

Comment: Thank you, I tried your updated code but I still get the same message

Comment: Did you use copy and paste, or type it? What OS do you use? Do you have an image named `top.jpg` to use as the top image?

Comment: I copy pasted, I am working on Windows 10, I do have an image named top.jpg, thus my imagemagick version is 7.0.2-0 Q16 x64. Btw does the command work on your machine?

Comment: another question what does `png:-` do?

Comment: Of course it works on my machine! ;-) The first `png:-` means that `montage` should write its resulting image as a `PNG` image onto its standard output, and the second one means that `convert` should expect to read a `PNG` image from its standard input and, as I joined the standard output of `montage` to the standard input of `convert` using the pipe (`|`), the image should pass from one program to the next.

Comment: Try replacing both `png:-` with `miff:-`

Comment: replacing both png:- to miff:- did not change anything, the command line does not give me any feedback

Comment: And if you type `convert /?`

Answer (score 0):

This is just another way of doing this. I think it may be a little simpler than Mark's solution. Note the parentheses that groups commands into single image ouput. Also remember that IM requires space before and after the openining brackets.

```
magick -gravity center -background none -bordercolor none ( f1.jpg -border 10 ) ( f2.jpg f3.jpg f4.jpg -border 10 +append ) ( f5.jpg f6.jpg f7.jpg -border 10 +append ) -append output.png
```

More on appending is [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/layers/#append) however in most cases I prefer [montage](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/montage/) command.